# Anyone know a SQL schema (scripts or something) for a forum's Start up?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, forum

We are searching for a while now on google to find out some good SQL scripts to 
create a "forum". Does anyone know some great start up kit (Image, scripts, schema view) from what I could start? We want something with the most functionalities as possible (such as number of views, ranking, etc).

Comment: To all those people who didn't like the wording: Cut the newbies some slack, please. reopening.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. It's even more difficult when you talk french to try to make people understand you. Maybe this is why this question looks like a "not real question".

Comment: @Simon: Add "PS: English is not my native language." to your posts. Otherwise it's hard to tell if you're "just" some sloppy script kiddie who doesn't really care :-)

Comment: I usualy add it but sometimes, people just remove this mention from my question ... so I decided to stop adding it! I do my best!

Comment: Then you did what you could. Everything else is no longer your fault :-)

Comment: @Aaron : Thank you. Fun to see that there's still people who care about others. But tell me, what is realy "wrong" with my question? So I'll be sure to ask "real question" next time.

Comment: It sounds like you were too lazy to type "forum software" into Google or maybe people objected to "good" (you didn't say what good means for you).

Comment: Well, maybe it's because of my english, but every search I've maded into google resulted into forums where people who maybe didn't realy know much about what they're talking about or subject that were simply just off topic. Probably because "forum" and "database" where too generic. And because of my "poor" english I were unabled to get specific search result. So I get to Stack ... Anyway, I'll keep it for me next time. Thanks again Aaron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the existing forum projects like [phpbb](http://www.phpbb.com/).

Comment: +1 for answering a 'not a real question'

Comment: Thank you for answering my "not real question".